# How do I mass assign from a form_tag param using STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, single-table-inheritance, sti

I am using STI to create a app which has a User parent and two children Employer and Jobseeker. The relationships have been setup and tested.

I want to use STI to store Employer Users and Jobseeker Users into Postgres using only 1 users controller.

I am inputing the details using a form_tag. I have created

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :user_type, :jobseeker %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :user_type, :employer %>
```

So the User controller can identify the type of input (Employer or Jobseeker)

The user controller create action is as follows;

```
if params[:user_type] == "employer"
  @employer = Employer.new(params[:employer])
  @employer.save

elsif params[:user_type] == "jobseeker"
  @jobseeker = Jobseeker.new(params[:jobseeker])
  @jobseeker.save

end
```

I can see the all the correct params in the debugger when I type params. And using the above method I can create a record that has a type jobseeker or employer.

I just can't get the rest of the data into the Db because I have no param "handle" to work of.

Comment: `rest of the data` means?

Comment: You can still use `form_for`.. If you want this way I will guide you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested names for fields to separate user attribute related params from other params values. Here I am using `user` for names of fields :

**View:**

```
<% form_tag .. %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'user[name]' %>      #Assuming you have name attribute
    ...
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'user_type', 'employer' %>
<% end %>
```

**controller:**

```
if params[:user_type] == "employer"
  @employer = Employer.new(params[:user])
  @employer.save

elsif params[:user_type] == "jobseeker"
  @jobseeker = Jobseeker.new(params[:user])
  @jobseeker.save
end
```